# LineRenderer inside Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm currently experimenting with LineRenderer inside Unity and I've found one really odd thing with it : Since I'm drawing connections between vertices I wanted to draw two lines from a single vertex. I have noticed that LineRenderer draws polylines. How can I draw two lines from a single vertex? Should I create another LineRenderer to do so?

Image of my problem here :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create two lines which would visually look to the player as two different entities, and not one line curved at the middle point, you should use two different Line Renderers for this.